# Shortest way to print "Success"

Tags: c

I have been trying this problem [SUCCESS](http://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/problems/SUCCESS/) at spoj but I am not able to get optimal solution to that problem

I tried

```
int main(){return !puts("Success");}
```

but it takes 45 characters. Any alternate suggestions to solve the problem? People have solved it using 24 characters also.

Comment: what are the rules on compiler flags?

Comment: no explicit rule, other than a suggestion of -ansi, and  gcc 4.3.2

Comment: @Kenny: This isn't a contest, as some other [code-golf] questions are, and I don't see why it should be CW. (But it's irreversible now, anyway.)

Answer (score 6):

```
main(){puts("Success");}
```

24 characters.

- in C, if you omit the return type, it is implicitly `int`
- if main() does not contain a return statement, then the return value of main is 0

**UPDATE:**
All right, the return from main *can be omitted in every version of C*, but only C99 defines the return value *to be 0 if omitted*. C99 also disallows implicit declarations.

**UPDATE:** 
I have faint memory that somebody pulled this off for a similar problem: He/She somehow encoded most of the program in the **file name** so that the __FILE__ macro could be used in the program code to inject the code. I don't know if this is within the rules for OP's competition, but it should make an interesting exercise anyway.

Comment: this gives NZEC error because we are required to return 0 and use int main,try it yourself.

Comment: WTF is NZEC? The problem statement on the site does NOT say anything about `return 0` or `int main()`. This is perfectly valid C.

Comment: @Luther It looks like the contest uses ANSI C, where the return in main() cannot be omitted.

Comment: In the current version of C, you are allowed to omit any `return` statement in the body of `main`, you are not allowed to omit the return type (`int`) in the function declaration.

Comment: @Chinmay: I believe it stands for Non-Zero Error Code and is one of the requirements for all problems.

Answer (score 5):

The problem statement is very vague, it look like it needs to compile with `gcc -ansi` and return 0 when run. Best I could come up was this:

```
main(){exit(!puts("Success"));}
```

32 characters counting the final newline (can you omit that?). Adding `int` to `main()` puts it at 36 characters.

#### Edit

This probably won't be allowed:

```
/* Filename: Success */
main(){exit(!puts(__FILE__));}
```

Compile with `gcc -x c -ansi Success` and it will save you another character!

And what about this one character solution:

```
C
```

Just compile with `gcc -ansi -DC='int main(void){puts("Success");return 0;}'`.

Comment: I have no idea how guys there have solved it using only 24 characters or did they cheat :P ?

Comment: what does -DC option do? I am not allowed to change compiler flags though.

Comment: -D gives the preprocessor a `#define` statement from the command line - so he's defining `C` to be `int main...`, and then the file itself is a single `C` which is replaced with the program from the command line.

Comment: @Samuel: `-DC` defines a preprocessor constant, just like `#define`. So the solution above is just moving the entire program into the command line. :)

Comment: Code golf scores would generally have to count excess characters of command line arguments against a solution.

Answer (score 5):

## 26 characters

```
main(){brk(printf("%m"));}
```

Comment: WTF is the use of `brk` here? Just a random bogus way to put 0 in `%eax`?

Comment: I hold the current record(24) in the judge for this problem,and that is very close to my solution,except I don't used any brk().

Comment: @Quixotic I am solving this problem since last 6 months, and I am still unable to figure out how to solve it in 24 chars, what should be used instead of brk() ??

Comment: @avinashse: Just printf() will do! :-)

Comment: @Quixotic: No it will not, `printf` expects at least one argument.

Comment: @Quixotic  I thaught about this :- printf returns number of characters printed to STDOUT and that cant be 0
  but main takes the value stored in register ( supplied by printf )
 that register has a limit of max val
  beyond that it will overflow
  i.e max+1 = 0 for that register, in this way we can do this and can return EXIT_SUCCESS to system but I am unable to figure it out how :( :(
there must be some arguments used in printf() which is doing the above task and returning 0

Comment: @avinashse: You are right. Indeed there is an argument when used in `printf()` guarantees (at-least in the SPOJ system) the right EXIT_STATUS. It took me some time to figure it out. I am sure you would too. Don't give up. :)

Comment: @Quixotic  I am unable to figure out that 3 letter words inside the printf(), it will be really helpful if you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

**[26](http://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/ranks/SUCCESS/)**

```
main(){j0(!printf("%m"));}
```

Comment: Neat. Does it compile without -lm?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. Bessel function of positive number is not zero. So spoj won't accept it.

Comment: Close. Hint for the 24 long solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Unix

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){perror(0);}
```

Comment: Gcc 4.3:

: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’

: In function ‘main’:

: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘perror’

: warning: control reaches end of non-void function

rbo

Answer (score 1):

30 characters:

```
main(){exit(!printf("%m\n"));}
```

29 characters:

```
main(){exit(!printf("%m
"));}
```

Comment: How does this print success??

Comment: It uses the common `printf` extension whereby `%m` is a specifier for `%s` with `strerror(errno)` as its string. The string for "error 0" is traditionally "Success".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one in 24 chars...

```
main(){puts("Success");}
```

Neither the `int` return type for `main()` nor the `return` statement are strictly necessary...

Comment: This may have been true before 1999, but now C requires an explicit `int` for a return type.

Comment: with -ansi one run gave 8 as return value... so return can't be considered implicit for ansi anyway, while missing int is fine it seems

Answer (score 0):

Making it smaller relies on doing things which are not portable or strictly valid C. On a POSIX environment with lax enforcement of the rules, you can do (18 characters):

```
main(){perror(0);}
```

But unless `int` and pointers have the same size, this will break. Adding 1 extra character and taking advantage of the fact that real-world POSIX systems have `long` and pointer types the same size:

```
main(){perror(0L);}
```

I don't think you can make it any smaller.

Comment: nice steal, mate. given the huge amount of results grepping Success in /lib and /usr/lib gives, there may just be another way.

Comment: though, perror prints on stderr. spoj wants it on stdout and they want an exit code of 0

Comment: On GNU systems: `main(){return printf("%m\n"),0;}`.

Answer (score 0):

I made it in 0 (zero) characters:

```
 cat src.c

 (empty)
```

the resulting executable:

```
rbo@deneb ~
$ ./src
SUCCESS
```

and the command line:

```
rbo@deneb ~
$ echo x>>src.c && gcc -Dx="int main(){return puts(\"SUCCESS\");}" -o src src.c
```

But this of course still creates a source file with on character, as [Pedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409157/pedro-rodrigues) has pointed out below. Without any source file, the command would be (in a Unix environment):

```
rbo@deneb ~
echo 'int main(){return puts("SUCCESS");}'|gcc -ansi -o src -xc -
```

which is even shorter than the above. In the original description, there's no restriction stated how to solve it, but the OP adds in a later comment he can't change the command line. If this is true, then this is *not really* a **Code Golf** ;-)

Regards

rbo

Comment: That isn't truly zero, since you're writing "x" to the source file, before compiling. Besides in the problem in question, I think the programmer has no control over the compilation flags.

Comment: Pedro, you are right. I edited the answer after your remark. How is this a "Code Golf" if such approaches are not wanted ;-)